# Inner loop apparently getting stuck

Tags: javascript, loops

When I run the following code, it only logs one loop; but, when I remove the inner loop it runs all 5 times as it should.  What am i overlooking?

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var fieldset = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[i];
  console.log("fieldset", i);
  var params = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    params.push(fieldset.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value);
  }
  console.log(params);
}
```

Comment: you are using the variable i in your inner and outer loop

Comment: change the variable on the inner loop. Javascript is function scoped hence the at the end of the inner loop the exit condition of the outer one il also meet

Comment: wow. omg. thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the same variable, `i`, in both loops.

---

To include and expand upon information posted as comments to this answer:

It is only an issue that you're using the same variable because you used the keyword, `var`. If you had used the keyword `let` instead of `var`, you wouldn't have the issue.

This is because `var` is function-scoped, while `let` is block-scoped.

Comment: This is the correct answer because in both places `i` is declared with `var`.

Comment: OP could also change from `var` to `let` and keep the variable

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the @DerpKat answer, you can also use `let` instead of `var` so the variable name `i` will be scoped to the loop block and the common name will not collide

Answer (score 0):

You get the elements in advance by using different variables for the loops.

```
var fieldsets = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset"),
    params,
    inputs,
    i, j;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    inputs = fieldsets[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
    params = [];
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        params.push(inputs[j].value);
    }
    console.log(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already  mentioned in the answer by DerpKat you are using the same variable `i` with var keyword. You can change the variable name in either of the loop or can use `let` which has block scope for the variable `i` in the inner loop

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var fieldset = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[i];

  var params = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    params.push(fieldset.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value);
  }
  console.log(params);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
  <input type='text' value='1'>
</fieldset>
```